# Django Create Form issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have a simple issue that I do not really know how t solve. 
I am using the Create form using model_form.html. The thing my html is within a template folder in that way : App_name>templates>model_form.html

The thing is that django is looking in App_name>model_form.html not including the template folder. I get that error message :

```
raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: website/project_form.html
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views import generic
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView, UpdateView, DeleteView
from .forms import InviteForm
from invitations.models import Invitation
from .models import project

class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = project
    fields = ['project_name']
```

url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from website import views

app_name = 'website'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^candidateIndex/$', views.CandidateIndex.as_view(), name='candidate_index'),
    url(r'^HRIndex/$', views.create_invite, name='HR_index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.DetailView.as_view(), name='ProjectDetails'),
    url(r'^project/add/$',views.ProjectCreate.as_view(), name='addproject')
]
```

my HtML:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Welcome to SoftScores.com</h1>
  <h2>Team analytics platfom</h2>
  <h3>Welcome to {{User.username}}, it is your Page</h3>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="">
    Create a new project :<a href="{% url 'website:addproject' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
  </div>
  <p>
    <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
      Create a new team
    </a>
  </p>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="card card-body">
      In order to create a new team please invite new members. A link will be sent to them in order to give the access to the application
    </div>
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ invite_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

</div>



{% endblock %}
```

Could you help me to link it ?thx

Comment: Did you add the app to your INSTALLED_APPS in settings?

Comment: yes of course .. the app is working .. it is when I click on the link website:addproject django should find directly the model_form.html .. I get this error :raise TemplateDoesNotExist(', '.join(template_name_list), chain=chain)
django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: website/project_form.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django expects looks for the template in a subdirectory of your app's templates directory:

```
websites/templates/website/project_form.html
```

It sounds like you currently have the template at:

```
websites/templates/project_form.html
```

Yo can either move the template, or explicitly set `template_name` for your view:

```
class ProjectCreate(CreateView):
    model = project
    fields = ['project_name']
    template_name = 'project_form.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put your templates within an app, the folder structure needs to be `project_name > app_name > templates > app_name > template_name.html`. This is generally used for standalone reusable apps.

More usually, you would put them in a project-level templates folder, where you would just need `project_name > templates > app_name > template_name.html`.